# Clean tests and Improve test redability to avoid problems between mocks

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, code-cleanup

Imagine the situation where I have several integration tests that validate the successful processing of a Product, under different conditions.

This Product has Id, Name, and Description. The description only accepts clear text, but I want to start accepting some HTML elements as well - Needless to say that I am considering [XSS attacks](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-prevent-xss)

To validate the HTML tags I'm using [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Safelist.html) which allows me to define only the HTML tags I want to allow.

This will be an example of the code I will use to mock the product, bearing in mind that for each case I need a `setDescription(description)` with different values:

```java
private Product buildProduct() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("ProductName");
    product.setDescription("<p>Description</p>")
}
```

That said, I will have to mock the product in three different ways:

- Product mockup with description without HTML tags
- Product mockup with description with valid HTML tags
- Product mockup with description with invalid HTML tags

I thought of creating a `buildProduct()` for each case, but this leads to code duplication.
I thought about splitting this into three different and isolated tests, but it doesn't seem to make sense to create several different tests for similar situations.

What will be the cleanest way to do this, **bearing in mind that the objective is not only to validate the tests but also to make the test as clean and readable as possible?**

Comment: Are you using Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Hey João, I'm using Java and Spring Boot

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Java, there is no nice way to do this. The reason is that there is no nice way to copy an object and change one or more properties, just like you can do in Kotlin (check [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) for further details).

Having said that you have two options.

The **first** one is creating a utility class that actually creates all these different objects. Yes, code would be duplicated but at least this ugliness would be hidden in a very specific file.

```java
public class TestObjects {
    public static Product productWithDescriptionContainingNoHtmlTags() {
       Product product = new Product();
       product.setName("ProductName");
       product.setDescription("No HTML Tags");
       return product;
    }
   
    public static Product productWithDescriptionContainingValidHtmlTags() {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("ProductName");
        product.setDescription("<p>Description</p>")
        return product;
    }
   
    public static Product productWithDescriptionContainingInvalidHtmlTags() {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("ProductName");
        product.setDescription("<invalid>Description</invalid>")
        return product;
    }
}
```

Then in your test class, you would only need to use these methods where suited.

The **second** one could be adding a constructor to your `Product` class that receives both `name` and `description`:

```java
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Product() { }

    public Product(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Then in your test class, you could do something like this to create such objects:

```java
private Product productWithDescriptionContainingNoHtmlTags = 
      new Product("ProductName", "No HTML Tags");
private Product productWithDescriptionContainingValidHtmlTags = 
      new Product("ProductName", "<p>Description</p>");
private Product productWithDescriptionContainingInvalidHtmlTags = 
      new Product("ProductName", "<invalid>Description</invalid>");
```

---

As a side note, one nice trick when you need to test some different scenarios without creating multiple tests is using Parameterized tests. Something along the following lines:

```java
private static Stream<Arguments> products() {
    return Stream.of(
      Arguments.of(new Product("ProductName", "No HTML Tags"), true),
      Arguments.of(new Product("ProductName", "<p>Description</p>"), true),
      Arguments.of(new Product("ProductName", "<invalid>Description</invalid>"), false)
    );
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("products")
void assertProductsValidity(Product product, boolean isValid) {
    // Your test here
}
```

Check https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#6-method for more details.

Comment: Hey João, thanks for your reply!

Well, the first case was what I thought and I wanted to make it cleaner.
I know the parameterized tests and have already used them in other concepts.

At the moment I followed with the first approach, but the idea will be later to make a refactor. 
And I really liked the way you made the argument stream to start the various objects, thanks for the tip!

Comment: You are welcome! Consider accepting the answer if you feel like it ;) Or not and leave it open for possible new / better approaches.